# Do I need a permit for putting retrievable sensors in ocean (Atlantic)?

Tags: ocean

The project would be to place about a dozen sensors in "swarm" fashion and have them collect data from the Atlantic ocean.

The sensors would be about the size of a softball and would be retrieved days later after data is collected.

I've been looking at regulations and permits needed for this but only find construction based permits for building homes or factories near the ocean.

Is there a permit I need to pull for this or a body who regulates this kind of research?

And would a different permit be needed if the sensors weren't meant/or unable to be retrieved?

Comment: Would the sensors be released in national waters, in the exclusive economic zone, or in international waters? Do you have contacts to a marine research institute?

Comment: Definitely within Territorial Waters (<12 miles from shore) and i don’t have ties to an institution it would be a private/independent project.

Comment: If it is in the 12 mile zone you should contact the governmental agency responsible for maritime affairs. In Germany, it would be the [BSH](http://www.bsh.de/en/Marine_uses/Science/Research_activities/index.jsp) where you need to applied 6 weeks in advance. In countries consisting of federal states, possibly a state agency might be responsible for research activities close to the shore and a federal agency in regions beyond close-to-shore until 12 mile. Which is the country, which we are talking about?

Comment: East Coast USA Atlantic Ocean.

Comment: The [National Oceanic and Atmospheric Administration](http://www.noaa.gov/) would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

It depends where you live as laws verry from country to country. Just ask your local lawyer or law enforcement official. It may also depend on what data you are recording